# Does An Inherited Class Have to Use the Same Parameters As Its Base Class For Dependency Injection To Work?

Tags: c#, inheritance, dependency-injection

If I were to do the following in an inherited class, in order to DI param3...

**Inherited class**

```
public class test2 : test1
{
    public test2(type param1, type param2, type param3) : base (param1, param2) {}
}
```

Would it work, since test1 class does not have param3 in its constructor?

**Base class**

```
protected test1(type param1, type param2)
{
    ...stuff
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you are asking. But in general, no: there is no requirement that constructor signatures must match in order for dependency injection to "work." Here you are injecting the param3 dependency into the test2 class, which is fine. However, you probably need to store or do something with param3; that is not shown in your code snippet.

Comment: Yes, if a `test2` is being injected, then the constructor defined in `test2` would be used.

Comment: @srk The dependency would be param3 in test2 class.

Comment: The container only cares about the dependencies of `test2`. As long its dependencies are registered, it doesn't care what `test1` requires. `test2` is responsible for that when it calls `base()`.

Comment: @madreflection So in this case, I am good calling test2 with 3 params even though base only has 2?